# accessing variable outside awk in linux

Tags: linux, shell, awk, ksh

```
file= input.txt
br=0
awk -v 'BEGIN{FS=";"}
{
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
{
print $i
br = NF
}
}'<$file
print "value of br " $br
```

I am storing the value of NF in br, so that i can use it further in script. In my case the value of NF is 10. but in br I am receiving 0.

Comment: Be careful what you are asking for.  Do you want NF, the number of fields, or NR, the number of records (lines)?  In your question these are confused.  The title says NR but the code says NF.

Comment: Does `wc -w ${file}` show something useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing shell scripts and awk, which are different programs/interpreters.

What happens in `awk` stays in `awk`.

The best you can do is print a string to the shell.

I note that I did not need the `-v` tag, and substituted the `-F` tag for setting `FS`.

In your case you might use the END directive in awk, which only runs at the the end.

```
file= input.txt
br=0
gawk -F; '
{
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
{
print $i
br = NF
}
}
END { print "final value of br:"br } '<$file
```

If you need this number in a shell environment variable called br, you could do it this way:

```
file= input.txt
br=$( gawk -F; '
{
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
{
br = NF
}
}
END { print br } '<$file 
)
```

### How It Works

In bash shell

`VARNAME=$( command )`

runs the command and sets the environment variable `VARNAME` to the output from running the command.

### Important: Use source instead of executing to set variables from shell scripts

Note that if you stick this in `br.sh` and `chmod 700 br.sd`, you might be tempted to run it with `./br.sh` which will run it, but it will set shell variable `$br` in the resulting temporary child process, not the calling parent.  The parent will have `$br` empty in that case. To get `$br` set in the parent, you would have to run the command file with `source br.sh` not by executing it directly.

Comment: but i want to use this br variable further in my script?